# Mongoose Populate virtual returns array within an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, virtual, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate a child document ["ENROLLMENTS"] with a foreign key but when there are multiple matches it returns an array of enrollments inside an array. When there is only one match it returns a single array with one object. Not sure why this is happening or a fix.

expected:
 enrollments [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]

actual:
 enrollments [ [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] ]

Below I have the schema for a client which has a virtual for enrollments. These are related by a combination key of assigner and value. Currently, I am trying to use the value to populate the document.

I'm open to other solutions as well.

Here is the client schema

```
 const clientSchema = new Schema({
   identifiers: [
     {
       value: { type: String, required: true },
       use: { type: String },
       assigner: { type: String, required: true },
       _id: false
     }
   ],
   ...
 },
 {
  timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdAt', updatedAt: 'updatedAt' },
  toJSON: { virtuals: true }
 }
);
```

Here is my virtual with the enrollments trying to match on the value field.

```
 clientSchema.virtual('enrollments', {
   ref: 'Enrollment',
   localField: 'identifiers.value',
   foreignField: 'subject.value',
   justOne: false
});
```

Here is enrollment schema

```
const enrollmentSchema = new Schema(
{
  organization: { type: String, ref: 'Organization' },
  identifiers: [
    {
      value: { type: String, required: true },
      assigner: { type: String, required: true },
      _id: false
    }
  ],
  subject: {
    value: { type: String, required: true },
    assigner: { type: String, required: true },
    _id: false
  },
  enrollmentDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  ...
},
{
   timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdAt', updatedAt: 'updatedAt' },
   toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});
```

Here is my populate method

```
 return await Client.find(query)
 .populate({
   path: 'enrollments',
   model: 'Enrollment',
   populate: {
    path: 'progressNotes',
    model: 'ProgressNote',
    options: {
      limit: 30,
      sort: { 'performed.period.start': -1 }
     }
   },
 })
 .select(Projections.CLIENT_FULL_WITH_ENROLLMENTS())
 .exec();
```

Here is what I get having returned

```
enrollments": [
 [
   {
      "subject": {
         "assigner": "2.16.840.1.113883.3.3519.6.1.32",
         "value": "5"
       },
      "identifiers": [
          {
             "value": "52",
             "assigner": "2.16.840.1.113883.3.3519.6.1.32"
          }
      ],
      "_id": "5b1981dfac3d5a000fb92fc3",
      "progressNotes": [],
      "id": "5b1981dfac3d5a000fb92fc3"
    },
    {
      "subject": {
         "assigner": "2.16.840.1.113883.3.3519.6.1.32",
         "value": "5"
      },
      "identifiers": [
         {
           "value": "7",
           "assigner": "2.16.840.1.113883.3.3519.6.1.32"
         }
       ],
       "_id": "5b1981dfac3d5a000fb92fc2",
       "progressNotes": [],
       }
      ],
      "id": "5b1981dfac3d5a000fb92fc2"
      }
   ]
  ],
```

Comment: This is a "self join". Are the "related" items perhaps always in the same document anyway? Or are they actually coming from different documents?

Comment: The enrollments and the clients are in different document collections

Comment: Show some sample documents you expect to "join" and your expected response then. If you give people data from which they can reproduce an expected result then it makes your question much clearer and gives people something to work with.